# How to compare dates formatted as `Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022` in BusyBox/Alpine

Tags: shell, sh, alpine-linux, busybox

In shell (no bash because of Alpine) using BusyBox, how can I compare two dates both formatted as `Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022`?

I want to know which one comes first. `date` doesn't support this input format. I'm only interested in whole days. The time isn't interesting for me. So two dates on the same day but a different time are equal to me.

Of course I could put all the names of the months in a lookup table and use the index of the month as its integer value (to be able to compare) but I have the feeling I shouldn't be the one programming that out...

**Update:**

```bash
/opt/scripts $ a="Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022"
/opt/scripts $ date -d "$a" +%s
date: invalid date 'Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022'
/opt/scripts $ date --help
BusyBox v1.34.1 (2022-04-04 10:19:27 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [[-s] TIME]

Display time (using +FMT), or set time

        -u              Work in UTC (don't convert to local time)
        [-s] TIME       Set time to TIME
        -d TIME         Display TIME, not 'now'
        -D FMT          FMT (strptime format) for -s/-d TIME conversion
        -r FILE         Display last modification time of FILE
        -R              Output RFC-2822 date
        -I[SPEC]        Output ISO-8601 date
                        SPEC=date (default), hours, minutes, seconds or ns

Recognized TIME formats:
        @seconds_since_1970
        hh:mm[:ss]
        [YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
        YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
        [[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
        'date TIME' form accepts MMDDhhmm[[YY]YY][.ss] instead
/opt/scripts $
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in shell"?  You seemed willing to use `date`, so clearly external tools are allowed.  Use one (eg perl or python) to convert the date to an epoch time for that day at midnight, then compare.

Comment: I meant, I'm working in sh and not bash because my script will be running in Alpine

Comment: The way I read that help text, `date -D '%a %b %e %T %Z %Y' -d "$a"` _should_ work, but it does not: it still spits out the "invalid date" error

Comment: For those who "can't test because I don't have Alpine" -- `docker run -it alpine`

Comment: @glennjackman it's because the format you supply is the output format, not the input format.

Comment: `$a` is `Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022` which _does_ match the input format.

Comment: BusyBox `date` apparently won't take the input month as a string - only as digits... hm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install dateutils https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/dateutils . Use strptime to convert the date to seconds. Compare seconds.

```
apk add dateutils
a=$(strptime -f %s -i "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022")
b=$(strptime -f %s -i "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Tue Aug 30 12:01:38 GMT 2022")
[ "$a" -lt "$b")
```

Comment: unfortunately, my company doesn't allow me to install packages :( Otherwise I would've chosen this solution. I'm going with a lookup table now for the month names

Comment: In the end, I convinced some people to add the package for me. Though it was the BusyBox version, lacking the %Z. I hacked around that by doing `"%a %b %d %T GMT %Y"` (so I'm hardcoding GMT because it's always GMT in my case)

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me for parsing openssl client_s SSL cert expiration dates in alpine, without having to pull in the whole coreutils. The GMT tip was just the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may have to rely on awk:

```bash
/ # cat /etc/alpine-release
3.16.0

/ # echo $a
Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022

/ # TZ=GMT awk -v a="$a" 'BEGIN {
>     split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", months)
>     split(a, date)
>     gsub(/:/, " ", date[4])
> 
>     for (i=1; i<=12; i++) {
>         if (date[2] == months[i]) {
>             timestamp = date[6] " " i " " date[3] " " date[4]
>             print mktime(timestamp)
>             exit
>         }
>     }
> 
>     print "hmm, " date[2] " is an unknown month"
>     exit 1
> }'
1661860897
```

Comment: So this is basically using a lookup table. That's something I also mentioned in my question. I'm looking for something more slick. A look up table is my backup solution :)

Comment: This works great on my alpine busybox . "more slick"?  LOL!

Comment: :) To elaborate, in general, it's bad practice to program these things out yourself because its a very common thing and it's error prone to do which leads me to believe there must be a good solution out there instead of a DIY one. If not, then I'll happily accept my fate and put this in my production code.

Comment: There's bad practice, and there's self-restricting the available tools. Can you use a different image than alpine?

Comment: I do agree with you though: it's best to avoid reinventing wheels, especially IMO when it comes to datetimes and timezones. I just didn't see any alpine/busybox alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my alpine busybox copy of date doesn't recognize strings as month either.

You want "slick", stick with Glenn's `awk` solution, so long as the time functions work for you. I hacked out the least-*slick* kluge using just `echo`, `date`, `read`, `if`'s, and a lot of tempfiles - it's an ugly mess, but it works, and it was a fun exercise in using only the most basic stuff.

```
/tmp $ ./script
#! /bin/sh

cat "$0"
cd /tmp
echo "01">Jan
echo "02">Feb
echo "03">Mar
echo "04">Apr
echo "05">May
echo "06">Jun
echo "07">Jul
echo "08">Aug
echo "09">Sep
echo "10">Oct
echo "11">Nov
echo "12">Dec

echo "Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022">a_raw 
read -r a_raw<a_raw
echo "Fri Jun  3 09:26:55 CDT 2022">b_raw 
read -r b_raw<b_raw

read -r _ Mon DD tim z YYYY<a_raw
read -r MM<"$Mon"
date -d "$YYYY-$MM-$DD" +"%s">a_epoch
read -r a_epoch<a_epoch

read -r _ Mon DD tim z YYYY<b_raw
read -r MM<"$Mon"
date -d "$YYYY-$MM-$DD" +"%s">b_epoch
read -r b_epoch<b_epoch

if [ "$a_epoch" -lt "$b_epoch" ]
then echo "$a_raw ($a_epoch) is before $b_raw ($b_epoch)"
else if [ "$a_epoch" -gt "$b_epoch" ]
     then echo "$a_raw ($a_epoch) is after $b_raw ($b_epoch)"
     else if [ "$a_epoch" -eq "$b_epoch" ]
          then echo "$a_raw ($a_epoch) is same as $b_raw ($b_epoch)"
          fi
     fi
fi

rm Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec a_raw b_raw a_epoch b_epoch

Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022 (1661817600) is after Fri Jun  3 09:26:55 CDT 2022 (1654214400)
```

## original

What do you mean "`date` doesn't support this input format"?

Something like this ought to work in `sh`, though I confess I don't have an alpine handy...

```
a="Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022"
b="Fri Jun  3 09:26:55 CDT 2022"
a_epoch=`date -d "$a" +%s`
b_epoch=`date -d "$b" +%s`
echo "A: [$a] ($a_epoch)"
echo "B: [$b] ($b_epoch)"
if [ "$a_epoch" -lt "$b_epoch" ]; then echo "$a is before $b"; fi
if [ "$a_epoch" -gt "$b_epoch" ]; then echo "$a is after $b"; fi
if [ "$a_epoch" -eq "$b_epoch" ]; then echo "$a is same as $b"; fi
```

Should say something like

```
A: [Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022] (1661860897)
B: [Fri Jun  3 09:26:55 CDT 2022] (1654266415)
Tue Aug 30 12:01:37 GMT 2022 is after Fri Jun  3 09:26:55 CDT 2022
```

There are cleaner ways, but this should get you started.

Lemme spin up a container and try there, brb...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Alpine, please check the addition to my question.

Comment: Inelegant, but works. Might be useful to template something from, then clean it up. I'd still use Glann's `awk` if your time functions are working, though. A lookup table is your *slickest* bet.